# want to Implement WhatsApp like toolbar hide with DrawerLayout, NavigationView

Tags: android, xml, layout, hide, toolbar

I'm Using, DrawerLayout with NavigationView, TabLayout and ViewPager with this layout
TabLayout,ViewPager and NavigationBar is working proper but Scrolling effect is not as i needed.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:elevation="6dp">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/green"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:elevation="0dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/toolBar"
                android:background="@color/green"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:elevation="0dp"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
                app:tabTextColor="@color/textColor" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:overScrollMode="never"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/navigationItem"
            layout="@layout/drawer_layout" />
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

But i don't know what i'm missing everything is working fine but main toolbar is not hiding while scrolling. Is there any changes in Activity file ? 
Please help me in this problem

Answer (score 0):

Add  `Implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'`  design library into your Gradle dependency. Don't forget to add **NestedScrollView** after **AppBarLayout.**

Here is example NestedScrollView.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/></android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: i'm using  Implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
but i want to open new Activity on Click of NavigationBar .Suggest another solution.

Comment: You can open a new Activity by passing an Intent on onClick() method of your Navigation Bar(ActionBar) button. For implementation details you may follow this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/actions.html#java).

Comment: please check my answer. .

Comment: Good work Nitish, as I pointed out, you did implement NestedScrollView, which was essential in this case.

Answer (score 0):

i have done this using

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/nest_scrollview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            tools:context=".Activity.MainActivity"
            tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewPager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```